# Boolean keys with other data types in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I was going through some python dictionary links and found this.

I can't seem to understand what is happening underneath.

```
dict1 = {1:'1',2:'2'}
print dict1
```

output

```
{1:'1',2:'2'}
```

But if I add a boolean key to the dictionary, it gives something weird.

```
dict2 = {True:'yes',1:'1',2:'2'}
print dict2
```

output

```
{True:'1',2:'2'}
```

Does it only happen if we include Boolean into the dictionary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `True` is a built-in enumeration with a value of `1`.  Thus, the hash function sees `True` as simply another `1`, and ... well, the two get confused on re-mapping, as you see.  Yes, there are firm rules that describe how Python will interpret these, but you probably don't care about anything past False=0 and True=1 at this level.

The label you see (True vs 1, for example) is set at the first reference.  For instance:

```
>>> d = {True:11, 0:10}
>>> d
{0: 10, True: 11}
>>> d[1] = 144
>>> d
{0: 10, True: 144}
>>> d[False] = 100
>>> d
{0: 100, True: 144}
```

Note how this works: each dictionary entry displays the *first* label is sees for each given value (0/False and 1/True).  As with any assignment, the value displayed is that last one.

Comment: Might be worth adding a note that it's guaranteed that the last value is taken as the keys are overwritten so, `{True:1, 1: 2, 1: 3}` becomes `{True:3}`, this can actually be useful for some things

Comment: That's how assignment works; it's merely not as blatant with a dictionary construct.  However, I added the note and expanded it to the labels.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, the `keys` of a dict is stored as a `hash-slot` pairs, where `slot` consists of the `key-value` pairs under a certain `hash`. So the actual searching procedure of getting `value` by `key` in a dict is as follows:

1. Get the hash value of the provided key `hash(key)`,
2. Find the corresponding `slot` under the `hash` value,
3. Iterate over the `slot` to find the target key(name it as `tkey`) which satisfy `tkey == key`, then return the `value` of that `key`.

Therefore in Python, **Same `keys` could have different values if their `hashes` are not the same, while same `hashes` could have different values if their `keys` are not the same**. The `hash` value is computed by `__hash__` method and whether `key`s are same is controlled by `__eq__` method (or `__cmp__`).
For example,

```
class A:
    def __hash__(self):
        return 1

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False
```

Now, all the instances of `A` have the same hash value `1`, but all the instances are different (including compared with themselves):

```
a1 = A()
a2 = A()
print(hash(a1) == hash(a2)) # True
print(a1 == a2) # False
print(a1 == a1) # False
```

Let's see what they can be when serving as `keys` in `dict`:

```
b = {
    a1: 1,
    a2: 2,
}
print(b)
# {<__main__.A object at 0x000002DDCB505DD8>: 1, 
# <__main__.A object at 0x000002DDCB505D30>: 2}
```

### Why `True` and `1` cannot exist simultaneously in one dict

In this question (or most cases in Python), equivalent `hash` means equivalent `key`.

```
print(hash(True) == hash(1)) # True
print(True == 1) # True
```

The result(or say, the reason of this equality mechanism) is that each `hash slot` has only one `key-value` pair(because `keys` are equal). This makes it very fast to search the value since there is no need of iteration over the slot. Still, you can change this *equality* in your own code to realize multiple same-hash keys in dict.

```
class exint(int):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False
    def __hash__(self):
        return int.__hash__(self.val)

a = exint(1)

print(a) # 1
b = {
    a: 1,
    True: 2,
}
print(b) # {1: 1, True: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Python `dict` is a hash map - it indexes its keys by a hash function for quick lookup in memory. Since evaluation of `hash(1) is hash(True)` is `True`, Python sees both as pretty much the same key. Thus, you cannot have both `1` and `True` in any sort of hash store in Python (without implementing your own hash functions, that is).

Comment: The hash being equal is a consequence of the values being equal too; testing `1 == True` produces `True` too (because `bool` is an `int` subclass; `False == 0`, `True == 1`). `hash(1) is hash(True)` is *not* guaranteed (`is` is identity checking, not equality checking; it's an implementation detail of CPython that small `int`s are cached and hash to their own value, one which need not be preserved in other Python interpreters, or even future versions of CPython), and `hash(1) == hash(True)` is derived from the general hash rules (equality implies hash equality, but not the other way around).